# how do I find out the PID of this that I ran by typing ./x264 --threads=1 -o vidz.mkv paris_cif.y4m?

Tags: linux, bash

I already ran

```
./x264 --threads=1 -o vidz.mkv paris_cif.y4m
```

and it encodes a video from input file paris_cif.y4m to output file vidz.mkv

Now I want to know the PID of that.

Comment: `pidof x264` or `ps aux | grep x264`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in comments you can use `pidof` or `ps` but i find `lsof` fits your needs best. to look from a files perspective to not be confused with multiple processes

```
# pidof
pidof x264 | head -n1
# ps
ps a | grep -v grep | grep -w x264 | grep -oE '[0-9]+' | head -n1
# lsof
lsof -t $PWD/vidz.mkv
```